# R: Trimming dataframe based on most common column entry

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by, data-manipulation

I have the following dataset which I'm trying to trim (sample of the dataframe is below)

| Index | Grade |
| --- | --- |
| Ace_1_1 | A |
| Ace_1_1 | A |
| Ace_1_1 | B |
| Ace_1_1 | C |
| Ace_1_2 | A |
| Ace_1_2 | C |
| Ace_1_2 | C |
| Ace_1_3 | B |
| Ace_1_3 | B |
| Ace_2_2 | C |
| Ace_2_2 | A |
| Ace_2_2 | B |
| Ace_2_5 | C |
| Ace_2_5 | C |
| Ace_2_5 | A |
| Ace_2_5 | A |
| Ace_3_1 | D |

```
df2 = structure(list(Index = c("Ace_1_1", "Ace_1_1", "Ace_1_1", "Ace_1_1", 
                               "Ace_1_2", "Ace_1_2", "Ace_1_2", "Ace_1_3", "Ace_1_3", "Ace_2_2", 
                               "Ace_2_2", "Ace_2_2", "Ace_2_5", "Ace_2_5", "Ace_2_5", "Ace_2_5", 
                               "Ace_3_1"), Grade = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "C", "B", 
                                "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "D")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-17L))
```

I'm trying to trim it down such that for each index, only the most common grade would show. If there is a tie in frequency, the tied grades would be shown. If there's only one entry the entry would be show as well. The ideal output for the table above would be

| Index | Grade |
| --- | --- |
| Ace_1_1 | A |
| Ace_1_2 | C |
| Ace_1_3 | B |
| Ace_2_2 | C |
| Ace_2_2 | A |
| Ace_2_2 | B |
| Ace_2_5 | C |
| Ace_2_5 | A |
| Ace_3_1 | D |

I'm using the group_by() function by counting the frequency with mutate (Frequency = n()) but I'm having trouble subsetting the most frequent count. Appreciate if anyone could help me count here either using dplyr or even base R, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using data.table or dplyr, you can simply take the rows in each group where the count equals the max count:

```
library(dplyr)
count(df2,Index,Grade) %>% filter(n==max(n), .by=Index) %>% select(-n)
```

OR

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, .N, .(Index, Grade)][, .SD[N==max(N), Grade], Index]
```

Output:

```
     Index  Grade
    <char> <char>
1: Ace_1_1      A
2: Ace_1_2      C
3: Ace_1_3      B
4: Ace_2_2      A
5: Ace_2_2      B
6: Ace_2_2      C
7: Ace_2_5      A
8: Ace_2_5      C
9: Ace_3_1      D
```

Answer (score 2):

You may calculate the [statistical mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/3962914) for each `Index` and keep rows that only occur most frequently. You can then use `distinct` to keep only the  unique ones.

```
library(dplyr)

Modes <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  tab <- tabulate(match(x, ux))
  ux[tab == max(tab)]
}

df2 %>%
  filter(Grade %in% Modes(Grade), .by = Index) %>%
  distinct(Index, Grade)

#    Index Grade
#1 Ace_1_1     A
#2 Ace_1_2     C
#3 Ace_1_3     B
#4 Ace_2_2     C
#5 Ace_2_2     A
#6 Ace_2_2     B
#7 Ace_2_5     C
#8 Ace_2_5     A
#9 Ace_3_1     D
```